# Creating a tournament bracket with Google Apps Script tutorial - problems

Tags: google-apps-script

One other person asked a question about this script and problems; the suggested change for `onOpen` didn't help me.

There is a menu error with the `onOpen`.

> TypeError: Cannot call method "addMenu" of null. (line 12, file "Code")

When I run it and refresh the Google Spreadsheet, no option appears to use it next to "Help" as described in the [tutorial here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/bracket_maker#section4)

When I try to run the createBracket function I get the error

> TypeError: Cannot call method "getRangeByName" of null. (line 27, file "Code")

I tried a suggestion that appears in a similar question here and got the error message

> Cannot call SpreadsheetApp.getUi() from this context. (line 18, file "Code")

I wonder if there have been changes to the sheets or the app developer since the tutorial was written that I don't understand?

Any help appreciated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFrSe.jpg)

Comment: I've improved the formatting (for easier understanding). For getting more help you should post your code attempts within your question.

Answer (score 1):

**Did you do this?**

> Select cell A2 and go to "Data-->**Named and protected ranges**" menu and define a **range** called **"FirstPlayer"**. After completing this step, when you go to "Data-->Named and protected ranges" again, you should see "FirstPlayer" in the right hand pane. Selecting it should take you to cell A2.

**Here's a copy of the instructions:**

[image]

Comment: I did . . although now named ranges and protected ranges are separate choices.